# Oracle Forms Application DB Password Change

Tags: oracle, forms, oracleforms

Will it impact application when we change the Password of DB which the application referring?

Comment: Only if somebody has been silly enough to hardcode it somewhere. If your application just uses the default Forms login screen then 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for the login when your application starts then it doesn't impact the application.
If you've got a formsweb.cfg and in your config you have mentioned a userid, you should change it in this file also.